# PyMongo with Django and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, uwsgi

I have a Django app with a MySQL Backend and I want to use `MongoDB` to save some additional (non-relational) data. I don't want to use `MongoDB` with Django's ORM, just plain simple PyMongo. Where would I initialize `PyMongo` in order to have one connection pool that is shared between all my Python processes that get spawned by uwsgi?

My uwsgi config looks like that:

```
[uwsgi]
...
module = myapp.wsgi:application
virtualenv = /var/www/virtualenvs/myapp/
processes = 100
enable-threads = True
single-interpreter = True
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
vacuum = True
...
```

This creates 100 python processes where each of them has a separate MongoClient connection pool with multiple connections to MongoDB. This is very inefficient. How can I have one connection pool that is shared between all processes?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

PyMongo is thread safe, but not fork safe. uWSGI creates multiple processes by forking and each process will have it's own MongoClient.

[Is PyMongo fork-safe?](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#id3)

PyMongo will not share connections across threads. One way to reduce the no of connections to Mongo would be to decrease the size of the threadpool.

In PyMongo 3, pass maxPoolSize=1